# Need help in translating language function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

In wordpress to translate from one language to another i am using this code:

```
<select onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" name="lang">
   <option selected="selected" value="/">English</option>
   <option value="/?lang=fr">Fran&ccedil;ais</option>
   <option value="/?lang=pt">Portugu&ecirc;s</option>
   <option value="/?lang=es">Espa&ntilde;ol</option>
</select>
```

But now i want the language to be converted from navigation bar. That i made in `Appearance > Menu`.
The link that i have added on them is 
`http://siweldlaniger.oasysit.com/?lang=en` for english and respectively as in list box.

When i go from English to any other language it works, but when i am on another language and want to translate to other language, it does not work.

Can anyone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose non-english language than all your links in top menu have the same `lang` value.

If I choose `France` than links look like this:

```
English <a href="...?lang=fr">
Spain   <a href="...?lang=fr">
```

all links have `lang=fr` - incorrect !

Comment: Yes all links have <a href"../?lang=fr">. But i put different values in the menu of wordpress then why i gets changed? How it can work?

Comment: I use wordpress only with one language and I don't know what function or plugin can change `lang` value :/

Comment: I suppose that you use some plugin for "multi language" and this plugin (for example on french pages) add `lang=fr` to all links and overwrite all existing `lang` value. For english pages it doesn't add `lang=en` (because this is default value) and doesn't overwrite all existing `lang` value.